# Dapper arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I have the following code:

```
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
  {
      conn.Open();
      var datan = conn.Query<SodraCell>("SELECT Name FROM dw_datamarts_Sodra_Nyckeltal.dbo.KeyValues WHERE Company=@company", new { company = "Company1" }).FirstOrDefault();
  }
```

When I run this, I get an exception saying:

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

I don't know why. Why do I get this when I'm doing a query like this?

Here is my Model SodraCell:

```
 public class SodraCell
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What does the stack trace say?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Where can I find the output from the stack trace?

Comment: From the exception? The exception object contains the stack trace.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Ah. The funny things Is that I am remote debugging a sharepoint app, and when I do that, the intellisense get f*cked up. I can't inspect the objects..

Comment: Then logging, logging, logging, is your answer.

Comment: Can you add the code for the SodraCell model? Is there any arithmetic in that class?

Comment: Show us the table definition for `KeyValues` - as well as the **entire method** in which the code snippet you have included is from.

Comment: This question looks like it still needs a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think that you map your select to 'SodraCell' class. In select your get 'Name' filed, but in class 'SodraCell' your have other fields.

Comment: No, I only have the property Name in SodraCell.

Comment: try to use string. 
var datan = conn.Query<string>("SELECT Name FROM dw_datamarts_Sodra_Nyckeltal.dbo.KeyValues WHERE Company=@company", new { company = "Company1" }).FirstOrDefault();

double check that column 'Name' is exist in db 'dw_datamarts_Sodra_Nyckeltal.dbo.KeyValues'. may be you column is 'name' in db?

i think that exception is not in this peace of code